# Uncaught SyntaxError in jquery.d.ts file

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

I'm trying to transition my jQuery project into a Typescript project.  However, when I include the jQuery typings from the [DefinitelyTyped Github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts) using this method:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on line 27 of jquery.d.ts, shown below

```
declare module 'jquery' {
     export = jQuery;
}
```

I've done a bunch of searching about this problem, but I can't seem to find any solutions to this problem.  What am I doing wrong?

(I am using WebStorm as my IDE)

EDIT: 
Ok, I followed some instructions below and installed the jQuery typings via the npm terminal.  However, when I remove the ///reference import, I now get an error in Webstorm: TS2304 cannot find name '$'.  However, the code compiles to js and can run in the browser fine.  It's just annoying to have those errors in my console in Webstorm.  Is there something I need to add to get Webstorm to recognize jQuery?

Comment: this is a runtime error - neither the IDE error nor (likely) the Typescript compiler one. Not enough info to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

most recommended practice nowaday is instead of ///reference import, install separate type packages: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery as devdependency. (and ensure you're using latest ts compiler supports this)

Comment: Ok, I followed those instructions and installed the jQuery typings via the npm terminal.  However, when I remove the ///reference import, I now get an error in Webstorm: TS2304 cannot find name '$'.  However, the code compiles to js and can run in the browser fine.  It's just annoying to have those errors in my console in Webstorm.  Is there something I need to add to get Webstorm to recognize jQuery?